# Get the previous route name or uri in Slim 3

Tags: slim-3

Is there anyway in Slim 3 to get the previous route name or uri, similar to Laravel's `back()` helper?

It doesn't have to be specific to Slim, I am just trying to redirect back to the previous page.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want referer header value, you could do it like this:

```
<?php

$app->get('/route', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    // Get header from request object
    $refererHeader = $request->getHeader('HTTP_REFERER');
    if ($refererHeader) {
        // Extract referer value
        $referer = array_shift($refererHeader);
    }
});
```

This will return URI, obviously, not name.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks!